# Lync 2010 to 2013 Migration

Tags: migration, lync-2013

I'm tasked with upgrading out system from Lync 2010 to Lync 2013.  To do this requires co-existence.

I have our 2013 environment up and running.  Test users on the 2013 system can talk/IM/see presence of users on the 2010 system and vice versa.  Users are able to share the desktop and programs between systems.  The Edge servers are working.

I have found that the meet URL is not working if initiated by a user on the 2013 system.

A meeting will open up.  It will show the 2013 and 2010 user in the meeting but IMs only show on the user computer and desktop sharing fails, but does not give me an error only a warning that leads to the links below.

I have found info about the warning messages that are showing up in the local logs but am very gun shy about forcibly removing my Conferencing info on our production servers (http://blog.rassie.dk/2013/03/lync-multiparty-im-and-voice-fails/ and [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2169248d-aa77-4b19-8298-c6d55091f519/lync-multiparty-im-not-working?forum=lyncprofile)).

Are there any solutions I can test that are not as drastic?

Comment: Are you talking about internal only users meeting, or internal/external meeting ?

Comment: Only internal users.  Scenario doesn't work inside or outside the organization though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke with Microsoft and after being sent to the article posted (http://blog.rassie.dk/2013/03/lync-multiparty-im-and-voice-fails/) by support we decided to run the suggestions in the article.

Only difference is we ran it just to remove the old Conference Directory left over for 2007 Compatibility that was not in use.

In our case:

```
Remove-CsConferenceDirectory -Identity 1 -force
```

After a reboot of the new front end servers a conference started by a 2013 user was now usable by all participants.